# Is it possible to upload multiple files into gcp server at a time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have more then 500 files which I am uploading into gcp storage in every 10 minutes.
I am uploading these files one-by-one which is a time taken process.

So Is is possible to upload these files into bulk in one short on gcp ?

```
def upload_files(**kwargs):                                                     
    stock_codes = kwargs['data']                                                
    bucket_name = 'gcp-bucket-name'                             
    base_path = 'base_path'                                  
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(gcp-services.json")                
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)                                 
                                                                                  
    for filename in stock_codes:                                               
       svg_blob_name = f"{filename}.svg"                                                                            
       svg_blob = bucket.blob(svg_blob_name)                                                                 
       svg_blob.upload_from_filename('file_path')                                                                                       
                                                                               
      print(                                                                  
         "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(                                   
                 f"{filename}", svg_blob_name                                    
             )                                                                   
         )
```

Comment: Use multithreading in python to concurrently upload the files

Answer (score 1):

yes. i don't know which technology u use but it can achieved by
using gsutil for example. try the following command -

```
gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my-bucket
```

the -m flag here is enabling parallel copy

for more info checkout this link - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: I am using Python for uploading the files into gcp cloud

Comment: @Amitjoc - that detail that you are using Python should be in your question. Your code should also be in your question.